# Attempting to capture regex match but is missing the end of some of the strings

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

I am needing to match strings of the following format "a.b-c.d:e" ... but the ".b" is optional as well as ":e". a, b, c, d and e all should be decimal.

Here are some examples that should match: 2.2-1509, 15.2-1627.3, 16.1-69.48:1, 16-1.48:2, 17.1-275, 46.2-878.3, 58.1-301, 58.1-615.1.

The regular expression I have that works for all scenarios *except* ":e" is the following:

```
[^<p]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*?[\.]?[ ]?[\-][0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*?[\:]?[0-9]*
```

What am I missing? I do know I can switch out [0-9] for \d but did it this way for readability.

The VB.NET code I'm using is as follows:

```
dim lang as String

'lang would be retrieved here and is usually an HTML paragraph... below is an example
lang = "<p class=section-text>§ 2. Information is defined pursuant to § 2.2-803, 15.2-1627.3, and 16.1-69.48:1 and shall establish appropriations.</p>"

Dim r As Regex = New Regex("[^<p]?[0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*?[\.]?[ ]?[\-][0-9]*[\.]?[0-9]*?[\:]?[0-9]*")
Dim applyEvaluator As MatchEvaluator = New MatchEvaluator(Function(m As Match) applyCodeLink(m, shouldApplyColor))
lang = r.Replace(lang, applyEvaluator)
Return lang



Private Shared Function applyCodeLink(ByVal m As Match, shouldApplyColor As Boolean) As String
  Dim rStr As String = m.Value
  rStr = "<a href=""http://lis/code.aspx?cod=" & urlSuffix & """>" & m.Value & "</a>"
  If shouldApplyColor Then rStr = wrapLinkWithColor(rStr)
  Return rStr
End Function
```

Comment: Concerning readability, if you're asking for help with regex - especially in this community - I would GUESS that you're going to get the most help from someone who is equally good at reading `\d` and `[0-9]` and knowing they have the same meaning - maybe you are talking about readability for other programmers?

Comment: Yes I mostly meant readability for my co-workers ... I haven't worked with many that were regex experts :) Thus the post.

Comment: Oh, and as I recently discovered, `[0-9]` and `\d` are very similar (identical in some contexts [ASCII, I believe, for instance]). -- `[0-9]` means any digit from `0` to `9` inclusive, whereas `\d` means _any_ digit, which would include Burmese digits (`[၀-၉]`), Arabic digits (`[٠-٩]`), Malayalam digits (`[൦-൯]`), and sooo many more... So, if your data is purely Latin characters, they are functionally the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about vb, but maybe this will work:

```
(?<=[^0-9])[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?-[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?(:[0-9]+)?
```

Comment: looks good when I try using http://regexstorm.net/tester ... I'm trying in my project right now, standby.